# how to submit form jQuery ajax with passing parameters MVC Asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to pass dynamic parameters in $.ajax function.
For that i am using following code:

$(function () {

```
    var postData = 0;
    $('#Index').submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/Home/Index",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { 'tabindex':0},
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Inserted');
            }

        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

but still i m not getting the required result.
Can anybody tell me where i m wrong??

Comment: Do you mean passing dynamic parameters such as `dataType` into the `$.ajax()` call, or do you mean passing dynamic `data` to the file through ajax.

Comment: Also, `contentType` is what you send to the server (do you want to send json to the server?) and `dataType` is what you receive (you will receive html with what is above)

Comment: yes i mean passing dynamic parameters into the $.ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for this instead of passing addition parameters i have use hidden fields.

Answer (score 0):

Is contentType required?. In the data: {} part, you dont need single quotes around the 'tabindex' variable.

Maybe if you explain what the actual response you get back (via firebug etc) is and what you are trying to achieve would be more helpfull.

Comment: by removing the sing quotes around the 'tabindex' i m not getting the proper result. Please if possible provide me code.

Comment: Code for what? Are you looking to return a partial view or a json result? Why not post your controller action to show everyone what you are actually processing / returning...

Comment: i m just want to pass the form values and one addition parameter values named "tabindex" to the controller action.